# Template Designer and Generation Engine for data-driven PDF documents

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, report

I have used crystal reports and adobe livecycle for designing PDF templates and generating PDF documents from dynamic data, mainly using microsoft technologies.

I am now looking for the same type of features for linux and php, preferably with open source technologies. The designer can be either an application for linux or windows, a desktop application or a web based app, but the engine should be called from php (ideally from the same server) for generating documents and populating data, all in a linux environment.

Does anyone use anything like this and can suggest alternatives?

Thank you.

Comment: If this is being downvoted for not being a programming question, can you tell me where I should post it, so I can post on the right forum? Even though it does not have any specific development doubt, this is an integration issue and as such, I consider it as being software development and implementation related.

Comment: Don't fret too much if you are getting voted down, a lot of the time people think that if they can't answer a question its not worth answering... I know it sounds silly but that's the mentality of a minority of users here.

Comment: @Duenna I just wish people would justify their downvotes, so I can counter argument their opinion. Downvoting without any comment or justification does not help users to make better choices in the future when they are posting questions...

Comment: Possibly you want to look at http://www.cloudformatter.com/Nimbus as one possible solution. This is our open source project that is a web browser based template development application for XSL templates from HTML+CSS design components.

Comment: @KevinBrown I am using nimbus, but I would like to know if this is being maintained and is active, as I have noticed some errors and lacking features that I need. Can this be forked? It it still under development?

Comment: Yes and yes. We have been doing a lot lately on the css2pdf conversion scripts but would welcome nimbus help/forks. Please contact me through the website to get you all setup. I think we did not put the code in git yet, i will check today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this, so I will leave it here in case someone else is looking for anything similar.

I am using Apache FOP as the PDF generator. I have Apache Tomcat with FOP as a webapp installed on a server, I call it locally through PHP and am able to retrieve the PDF for the templates I need.

The designer I used for testing this was Altova StyleVision, but will take a look at Nimbus, as I usually prefer cloud solutions as they do not rely on the device I am using.

Thank you kevin for the suggestion.